# Make [ios-safari] a synonym of [mobile-safari]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

As far as I can tell, [ios-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-safari) (1 question) means the same thing as [mobile-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-safari).  As such, it would make sense to have [ios-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-safari) be a synonym of [mobile-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-safari).

Answer (score 1):

I retagged the one question tagged [ios-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-safari). Consider it burninated.

If this becomes a recurring issue, a synonym may be in order.